# What is [....] in C#

Tags: c#

I encountered this in some .Net Framework code. I've never seen it before. Anyone know what it means?

```
switch(msgFlags)
{
case Message.[....]:  // <-- never seen this before?
    // do some stuff
}
```

**Edit:** I was stepping through some of my code, when it threw an exception.  The exception broke on the lines somewhere in the Framework code. I can't remember now where at.  This was not a collapsed region.  The section is underlined in my editor with an 'Identifier Expected' error.  I'm wondering if it isn't some kind of placeholder for some super-secret secret squirrel code that Microsoft doesn't want anyone to see.

Comment: [Code goes here] is my first assumption.

Comment: Have you tried throwing that into a project to see if it compiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you found this in RealProxy.cs.  This looks like a search-and-replace mistake.  There are several places where the string appears:

```
// NOTE: Keep this in [....] with unmanaged enum definition in Remoting.h
           msgFlags = Message.[....];
           // cannot support Async and end up doing a [....] call. We need
        case Message.[....]:
```

Looking at the same code with Reflector, you see the literal value 0 being used.  Which means that Message.Dunno must be a const value.  There's one good match for that, Message.Sync is a private const with the value 0.  Good match too with // NOTE: Keep this in *sync*, and // cannot support Async and end up doing a *Sync* call.

This used to say "Message.Sync".

Comment: Levi (a Microsoft employee) indicates that such replacements are caused by an automated tool for removing information (e.g., developers' names) from the source code.  [See answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12114704)

Answer (score 1):

Do you see a little [+] sign next to the declaration?  Looks to me like you have the method collapsed.

Comment: Nope. This was not a collapsed section.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are seeing this in a book/blog/post etc.

It is simply a placeholder.  That isn't valid C# code.

Comment: Do you have a link to a copy of the source?

Comment: If you're still curious, the source is at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx