# Why does Microsoft's source code reference have two copies of the code in each .cs file

Tags: .net-4.0

So, I was looking in `[PATH]\RefSrc\Source\.Net\4.0\DEVDIV_TFS\Dev10\Releases\RTMRel\ndp\fx\src\MIT\System\Web\UI\MobileControls\Panel.cs\1305376\Panel.cs` and noticed that the file, as well as other files I checked, contained two exact duplicates (I checked by pasting both chunks into a diff tool) of the source code.  Like so:

```
[COPYRIGHT MESSAGE 1]    
[CODE]    
[COPYRIGHT MESSAGE 2]
[COPYRIGHT MESSAGE 1]    
[CODE]    
[COPYRIGHT MESSAGE 2]
```

Is there a reason for this? Some weirdness with version control or something?

I tried checking the [Reference Source Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/refsourceserver/threads) and saw someone [theorized](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/refsourceserver/thread/08e4f7c4-d448-42e8-ad3b-64c76f640a6d) that it's a bug in the installer, but I am curious if anyone can offer their own insight.

Comment: Ever find out why, Brian? I'm curious too. I installed it today and it's still the case - two of everything.

Comment: No, I didn't.  My suspicion remains that it's a bug in the installer.

Comment: A sinistre plan to deliver the source code while at the same time making compilation impossible?

Comment: Once there was a computer vendor that realised they could sell the computer for more if they put the electronics in a big (nearly empty) box, than if they put it in a small box. I used to have a collage lecturer that graded based on number of pages. He would drop it on a scale and read of the grade. Maybe Microsoft is trying to improve its grade.

Comment: Is probably a conspiration so people talk about Microsoft and they increment their sales. Pure marketing!

Comment: A bug in some post-processing tool, probably.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136242/what-is-in-c-sharp for another example.

Comment: @HansPassant: Interesting hypothesis.  That strikes me as more likely than it being a bug in the installer code itself.

Comment: It's backup. Duh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that later releases of the reference source do not include two copies of the source code, I'm going to guess that Hans Passant is probably right (in his comment) that this likely a bug in the tool that generates the source.

Answer (score 2):

Redundancy, when the first source is corrupt it gets validated or synchronized with the other.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my RefScr directory and downloaded a clean copy of the package Net 4.5 from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

I poked around and found the equivelent directory/file:

```
\RefSrc\Source\.NET 4.5\4.5.50709.0\net\ndp\fx\src\MIT\System\Web\UI\MobileControls\Panel.cs\550320\Panel.cs
```

When i manually broke the file into two parts I noticed the files were identical.

I saw the same issue in the newest distribution. I am going to dig in a little further when I get a chance today but now after further investigation I suspect it may have something to do with how the repository is managed.