# Why do I need to change "internalKeyToken" to "PublicKeyToken" in my resx file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources, porting, system.drawing

I have moved a C# solution file from VS 2005 to VS 2010, and on a new computer.  One issue I encountered is that the original version of the resource file mixed `PublicKeyToken` and `internalKeyToken` like so:

```
<data name="NAME" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
  <value>PATH;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, 
  Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
</data>
```

and

```
<data name="NAME" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
  <value>PATH;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing,
  Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, internalKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
</data>
```

This file was generated by Visual Studio 2005 via use of the designer, though I'm editing it by hand to change instances of `internalKeyToken` to `PublicKeyToken`.  Not doing so gives me a compiler error:

```
Error   19  Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified. Line 225, position 5.
```

So, I am wondering:

1. Why did Visual Studio 2005 somewhat arbitrarily switch between internalKeyToken and PublicKeyToken?  The files are all in the same format.
2. Why did that work before but now gives a "Could not load file" error? What has changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My crystal ball says that you had an out-of-control Search + Replace.  You replaced "public" with "internal" and accidentally modified the .resx file as well.  Just fix it or restore from source control.

Even the top dogs [make this mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136242/what-is-in-c-sharp).