# Weird variable name (_[....]) in .Net Source Code (HttpApplication.cs)

Tags: c#, .net

I was stepping through .Net Framework source code to find a tricky bug (HttpApplication.cs), and I noticed lines like these in the code (these are copy/pastes, I didn't edit anything):

```
_[....] = true;
```

and

```
_[....] = false;
```

I'm wondering if this is obfuscated code, or is this some sort of c# convention I've never seen before?  VS 2012 seems to think its not real code.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Literally `....`, or...? Anyway, it looks obfuscated.

Comment: Either this code has been through an obfuscator, or it has been written by a programmer who should be fired from whatever company that produced the code :)

Comment: the line is literally as pasted.  Theres actually a declaration at the top of the file, `private bool _[...];`

Comment: Maybe there's a tool that replaces this pattern by some computed value just before compilation (in the compilation toolchain)

Comment: If it was an attempt at obfuscation, then it is not very good, especially when you have a method like bool IExecutionStep.CompletedSynchronously { get { return _[....];} } which gives a pretty big clue about what it is for. Maybe the original variable was called async and someone did a search and replace to replace it with an invalid varible name just to see what breaks, and then forgot to change it back.

Comment: @sgmoore How could this be obfuscation? It's source code, not compiled binary.

Comment: @ken2k. It isn't normal, but obfuscation can apply to source code as well. By the way, it wasn't actually me that suggested it was obfuscation. I was just pointing out that it was unlikely.

Comment: I'm 99% sure it's not obfuscation, as the entity [....] is referenced in comments all over that source file. It seems to have some meaning that is approximately "synchronous processing" (e.g. it often appears in the "not async" case.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name of the field as it exists in the actual HttpApplication.cs code is "_sync".  There is an automated tool which is run over the source before it goes out to the general public; this tool scrubs things like developers' names, etc.  It looks like this was just a false positive.  I'll bring it up with the appropriate team to see if it can be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This particular token seems to show up *all over* the .NET reference source code. It's far more often used in comments than as a variable, but `HttpApplication.cs` is not the only place it shows up (`WeakKeyDictionary` uses it as a `lock` target, for example.)

In many cases. it's a synonym for the word "sync", as in:

```
InstancePersistenceContext.cs:1586: Fx.AssertAndThrowFatal(this.context.Active, 
    "Out-of-[....] between InstanceExecutionContext and ExecutionAsyncResult.");

EditModeSwitchButton.cs:64: // [....] to the owning PropertyContainer only if requested to do so
```

and my favorite, from an obsolete `System.Web.Mobuile` class:

```
TemporaryBitmapFile.cs: private void [....]()
```

My *best guess* as to where it came from is that it's a pre-publishing step that's done on the source code before it's released to the public (it appears in every copy of the reference source I've found, but *not* the SSCLI that was released a while back. Compare, for example, `RemotingProxy.cs:222`:

```
SSCLI: int callType = Message.Sync;
RefSec: int callType = Message.[....];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the source code includes a boolean variable named  `_[....]` . I guess the name of the variable could not be decided at the moment code was written; and it was forgotten to be fixed later.
http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/HttpApplication@cs/10/HttpApplication@cs

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare: Microsoft may have custom preprocessing as part of their build scripts.